# Como obtener el valor de una columna oculta en GridView para insertarla en una BD

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

Tengo un GridView donde varias de las columnas están oculta es decir **Visible="false"**.

Mi GridView llena sus columnas con la información de un archivo **.txt**, posteriormente esos datos cargados deseo incluirlos a mi **BD**.

El problema esta que al momento de hacer el **INSERT INTO**  me arroja el siguiente error:

**La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.**

Pero si las columnas mencionadas arribas no las coloco oculta es decir las coloco **Visible="true"**.

Puedo realizar el **INSERT INTO** sin ningún inconveniente.

Mi pregunta es Como Obtengo el valor de esas columna que he colocado oculta para luego insertarlas.

Anexo Código HTML del **GridView**:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" Width="100%">
   <Columns>
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Operador" HeaderText="Operador" >
       <ControlStyle Width="400px" />
       <FooterStyle Width="400px" />
       <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="400px" />
       <ItemStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Left" Width="400px" />
       </asp:BoundField>
   
       <asp:BoundField DataField="AcumuladoDeAnuladosMes" HeaderText="Acum De Anul Mes" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" Visible = "true" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="VentaBruta" HeaderText="Venta Bruta"  DataFormatString="{0:N2}" Visible = "true" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Anulaciones" HeaderText="Anulaciones"  DataFormatString="{0:N2}" Visible = "true" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="Devoluciones" HeaderText="Devoluciones" Visible = "true" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="VentasNetas" HeaderText="Ventas Netas"  DataFormatString="{0:N2}" Visible = "true" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="IVA" HeaderText="IVA"  DataFormatString="{0:N2}" Visible = "true" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="NetoAcumulado" HeaderText="Neto Acumulado"  DataFormatString="{0:N2}" Visible = "true" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalVentas" HeaderText="Total Ventas"  DataFormatString="{0:N2}" Visible="true" />


                   < !--ESTAS 2 COLUMNAS LAS COLOCO EN FALSE PUES NO DEBEN MOSTRARSE-- >
                   < !--SI LAS COLOCO EN FALSE ME DA ERROR-- >
                   < !--SI LAS COLOCO EN TRUE REALIZA MI INSERT-- >


       < asp:BoundField DataField="AcumPosPeriodoActual" HeaderText="Acum Pos Periodo Actual" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" Visible ="false" />
       <asp:BoundField DataField="AcumNegPeriodoActual" HeaderText="Acum Neg Periodo Actual" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" Visible ="false" />
       

   </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#FF9900" ForeColor="White"  HorizontalAlign="Right"/>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Size="Small" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" />
    <RowStyle Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Right" Font-Names="Arial" />
 </asp:GridView>
```

Anexo Código del **INSERT INTO**:

```
protected void btnInsert(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cs = (Session[CWAuthorization.kCWAuthorizationKey] as CWAuthorization).allowedStore;
        
        string server = cs + "sql";
        string bd = "HYPER+DB";
        string user = "UserReportePosWeb";
        string password = "R3p0rt3P0sW3b";

        string cadenaconexion = "Data Source=" + server +
                                ";Database=" + bd +
                                ";User Id=" + user +
                                ";Password=" + password +
                                "";
        SqlConnection conex = new SqlConnection(cadenaconexion);

        conex.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO REPORTE_Z4 VALUES " +
                                             "(@Operador," +
                                             " @AcumuladoDeAnuladosMes," +
                                             " @VentaBruta," +
                                             " @Anulaciones," +
                                             " @Devoluciones," +
                                             " @VentasNetas," +
                                             " @IVA," +
                                             " @NetoAcumulado," +
                                             " @TotalVentas," +

                                             " @AcumPosPeriodoActual," +
                                             " @AcumNegPeriodoActual)", conex);

        try
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Operador", Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Text.ToString().Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcumuladoDeAnuladosMes", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[1].Text.ToString().Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VentaBruta", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[2].Text.ToString().Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Anulaciones", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[3].Text.ToString().Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Devoluciones", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[4].Text.ToString().Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VentasNetas", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[5].Text.ToString().Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IVA", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[6].Text.ToString().Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NetoAcumulado", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[7].Text.ToString().Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalVentas", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[8].Text.ToString().Trim()));     

                // ESTAS DOS LINEAS ESTAN OCULTAS EN MI GRIDVIEW Y ES AQUI DONDE ME ARROJA EL ERROR
                // La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto. 

                // QUE PUEDO AGREGARLE A ESAS LINEAS PARA OBTENER EL VALOR DE ESAS COLUMNAS OCULTAS



                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcumPosPeriodoActual", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[9].Text.ToString().Trim()));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AcumNegPeriodoActual", Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells[10].Text.ToString().Trim()));

               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
            lblStatus.Text = "REGISTROS INSERTADOS";               
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblStatus.Text = "ERROR: " + ex.Message;               
        }
        finally
        {
            conex.Close();
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por algún motivo que desconozco, el atributo `Visible="false"` no permite que pueda ser recogido el campo, si deseas que el campo esté oculto pero que puedas obtener sus datos uses clases css que oculten el campo pero que permita su manipulación, por ejemplo:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="AcumNegPeriodoActual" HeaderText="Acum Neg Periodo Actual" DataFormatString="{0:N2}" ItemStyle-CssClass="hide" />

.hide {
    display: none!important;
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias por esta respuesta, ya era algo que había conseguido en internet, es sencillo y fácil.

Comment: Si es correcta mi respuesta agradecería que pulses en el tic verde, en caso de que sea otra te invito a que escribas tu solución

Comment: Amigo vote como Útil la respuesta tuya

Comment: @TheRiddler la forma de clasificar las respuestas, ademas de por la utilidad, es aceptando la que realmente contesta la pregunta. Si esta respuesta contesta la pregunta, por favor aceptala. Si no lo hace, por favor aclara que partes no cumple. Si tenes una respuesta mejor, por favor, agregala.

Comment: Listo, Gracias :)

Comment: @TheRiddler recuerda hacer eso con todas las respuestas que contestaron tus preguntas!!!!